# Clear a list of checkboxes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few programatically generated lists of checkboxes (uncontrolled) in my project, and I'd like a react-way to clear them all at the click of a button. My problem is, I have no way to reference them each.

I've tried setting refs but I can't seem to figure out how to share refs between a stateless child and it's parent (is this even possible?)

All I need is a button that, when clicked, unchecks all checkboxes. I never would have imagined this would be so complicated but I've been at it for an hour now and my head is starting to spin. Here is an example of one of the lists:

```js
{props.filters[0].map(jobType => (
  <li key={_.uniqueId('subType_')} className="checkbox text-sm m-b-sm">
    <label className="">
      <input type="checkbox" value={jobType.value} name="subtype" onChange={props.handleFilterCheck} />
      <span>{jobType.title}</span>
    </label>
    <span className="text-muted"></span>
  </li>
))}
```

So I have a way to consistently reference the size of the list and I know I could use iteration if I just had a way to reference the list but as it stands now that isn't possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a state variable (an object) that contains any checked checkbox, so initially it will be empty, when a checkbox is checked, add it to the state variable, and if the special uncheck all box is checked, clear the state variable to its default (an object).

Comment: this is basically what I did! after creating a checkbox component, I added a state variable as a set, not an object and from there it was trivial to manage the state of the checkboxes. Thank you for the inspiration!

Comment: you know that's the best solution ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've tried setting refs but I can't seem to figure out how to share refs between a stateless child and it's parent (is this even possible?)

It's not possible with functional components. `refs` only work on class components.

The other suggestion would be to convert all the checkbox to controlled inputs and then use props to pass in the checked state of `false`.

Or move the checkbox into it's own component that handles its own state:

```
{props.filters[0].map(jobType => (
    <li key={_.uniqueId('subType_')} className="checkbox text-sm m-b-sm">
        <CheckBox 
            value={jobType.value} 
            label={jobType.title}  
            onChange={props.handleFilterCheck}
            checked={/* Here you can manually override the checked state by passing in a bool */}
        />
        <span className="text-muted"></span>
    </li>
))}


class CheckBox extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: props.checked || false
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { value, title, handleFilterCheck } = this.props;
        const { checked } = this.state;
        return (
            <label className="">
                <input type="checkbox" value={value} name="subtype" onChange={handleFilterCheck} checked={checked} />
                <span>{title}</span>
            </label>
        )
    }
}
```

EDIT:

And last but not least, you can straight up target all the elements and set checked to false using pure JS and dom manipulation.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach( el => el.checked = false );
```

Comment: The problem with handling the checked status in state is that I have 20+ different checkboxes, which would make my state super messy. Your second answer works but it's not very react-y

Comment: You should create a `<Checkbox />` component that handles it's own state. So instead of you parent component keeping track of all the checkboxes and their states, you would have 20+ `<Checkbox />` components that handle their own state. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure, but then how do I reference all the subtype checkbox components and uncheck them? As far as I can tell your vanilla js querySelector is the only way I can feasibly do what I'm trying to accomplish so I'm gonna mark this as the answer

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the same question by creating list of `<Checkbox />` components. Then at parent level I used array state, which held all checked values. And one of the props to `<Checkbox />` components was boolean which was telling if parent array state is empty.

```js
const Parent = (someList) => {
  const [checkedArray,setCheckedArray] = useState([]);
  
  return(
    someList.map(el => <Checkbox key={el}
                                 empty={checkedArray.length === 0}
                                 value={el.value} /> 
                                 );
                                 );
                                 };
const Checkbox = ({empty, value}) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
        empty && setChecked(false);
    }, [empty]);
    
  return(
    //some checkbox JSX
    );
    };
```

I'm newbie so there might be some pitfalls.

Comment: useEffect is key, thank you, maybe, this is the only solution

Answer (score 1):

I came for this same problem, did a bit of thinking, and figured out a more "React" way.

I'm using checkboxes as a way to enter query parameters to call an api. We can use state to keep track of which checkboxes are currently checked. However, when rendering these checkboxes, we can set the checked attribute to be programmatically connected to our state. If the checkbox's value is in state, check it. Otherwise, don't.

We can then set up a button to reset this piece of state on click. Because state changes re-render the component, all of the checkboxes would re-render - setting checked to false.

```
const [selectedBoxes, setSelectedBoxes] = useState([]);
const renderCheckboxes = (items) => {
  return items.map(item => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      <input value={item.id} onChange={handleCheckbox} name="categories" checked={selectedBoxes.includes(item.id)} />
    </div>
  )
}
const handleCheckbox = (e) => {
  setSelectedBoxes([...selectedBoxes, e.target.value]);
}
return (
  <div>
    {renderCheckboxes()}
    <button onClick={setSelectedBoxes([])}>Click Me</button>
  </div>
)
```